# How to map Amazon Products API to Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-product-api, excon

I'm trying to fetch products from the Amazon Products API (using https://github.com/hakanensari/vacuum/) and display them in my Rails app. But how do I bring the product names and photos into my views?

Currently getting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `image' for #<Array:0x88486aec>):
    2: <% if @products.any? %>
    3:   <% @products.each do |product| %>
    4:     <div class="product">
    5:       <%= link_to image_tag(product.image.url), product.url %>
    6:       <%= link_to product.name, product.url %>
    7:     </div>
    8:   <% end %>
```

**main_controller.rb**:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    request = Vacuum.new('GB')

    request.configure(
      aws_access_key_id: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST',
      aws_secret_access_key: '<long messy key>',
      associate_tag: 'lipsum-20'
    )

    params = {
      'SearchIndex' => 'Books',
      'Keywords'=> 'Ruby on Rails'
    }

    #
    # NOT SURE WHERE TO TAKE IT FROM HERE
    #

    raw_products = request.item_search(query: params)

    @products = raw_products.to_h
    product = OpenStruct.new(@products)
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**:

```
<% if @products.any? %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product">
      <%= link_to image_tag(product.image.url), product.url %>
      <%= link_to product.name, product.url %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What is the type of `raw_products`? It apparently isn't an array or anything. Also, don't use `map!` if you are going to assign it to a different value. `map!` mutates the object you call it on, where `map` will just return the new value.

Comment: @JustinWood: Should I instantiate it as an array first, ie. `raw_products = []`? I'm not sure how to debug the actual response (`Rails.logger.debug("My response: #{request.item_search(query: params)}")` didn't return anything). Here's a similar setup using `map!` with the ShopSense API -- https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955 -- should I switch to `map` there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `raw_products` isn't an array. AS par `vacuum` documentation, you will either have to convert it to hash by `raw_products.to_h` or You can also pass the response body into your own parser for some custom XML heavy-lifting:

```
MyParser.new(raw_products.body)
```

So you have to first parse the the response properly before consuming it.

---

You can just do following:

```
  @products = raw_products.to_h
  product = OpenStruct.new(@products)
```

Comment: Like this `raw_products.to_h`? Still getting undefined method `map!` or `map` though. Also I'm guessing there's no need for the heavy-lifting?

Comment: yes, now you may be getting this because, this is hash, I don't know in what exact format your results are, you can try to print them and then decide how to use it, If it is a map, you may not be needing map at all, you may directly start using it.

Comment: I tried printing it out with `Rails.logger.debug("My response: #{raw_products}"` but I just got `My response: #<Excon::Response:0x82556cd4>`.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks man! Any idea how to make it work with `<%= link_to image_tag(product.image.url), product.url %>` in the view though? Updated question above.

Comment: rails views, I am not sure how to render :(

Comment: `Rails.logger.debug("My response: #{@products}")` now successfully returns JSON. If you see my similar setup with the ShopSense API, you can see how it's rendered in views: https://gist.github.com/frankie-loves-jesus/11058955 -- do let me know if you can think of anything.

Comment: Migrated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409950/how-do-display-amazon-product-api-in-my-rails-views